# Using OPOS in Delphi

Tags: delphi, opos

when I use TOPOSPOSPrinter.open using OPOS an "Interface Not Supported" error message comes up

I try to use a printer IBM4610 but when i use the driver OPUS this problem results.

The code compile.

CODE

```
function TCustomizedTenderPlugin.HandleEvent: WordBool;
var

  ret:Integer;

  mic : Pointer;

  {pruebas con opos}
  PosPrinter: TOPOSPOSPrinter;



begin
  {CREDENCIALES DE LA IMPRESORA . MODIFICAR DEPENDIENDO DEL TIPO}
   CargarIni(puerto);    

      try
         {Conexion con impresora}
         PosPrinter:= TOPOSPOSPrinter.Create(nil);
         PosPrinter.Open('4610_IBM',ret); // AQUI DA ERROR
         ShowMessage(VarToStr(ret));
         PosPrinter.Close(ret);
         ShowMessage(VarToStr(ret));
      Except
        // mensaje de error del 

        // me da Interface not supported
      end;


end;
```

Please I need help.

Thanks for your kind help :)

Comment: You've provided no useable info (even after your edit). You say `REC` is an integer, but you show nothing being assigned to it, and you mention that `IBM_4610` is a `WideString`, but show passing it as a constant that the compiler would probably automatically convert to the appropriate type.

Comment: Im Sorry its difficult to me explain the function because its from a dll . I use Opus Driver .

Comment: Sorry. You changed the entire question after I posted an answer; I'll delete it, since your original question asked something totally different.

Comment: Do you think it likely that anybody else here knows anything about OPOS?

Comment: How did you import the OPOS CCOs? There is no method Open(DeviceName, Ret) in the official 1.10 .. 1.13(Current) POSPrinter dll, the closest match is the function Open(const DeviceName: WideString): Integer;

Comment: WHAT is `TOPOSPOSPrinter`?  Mentioning you have a problem using a class name defined in your source code is like me saying that I'm having trouble with the table saw that we, around our shop refer to as Freddy the Table-saw. Has anyone got any tips for operating Freddy safely?  Seriously. Go find what TOPOSPOSPrinter is defined as, and tell people.  My best guess is it's an ActiveX wrapper class around a control in a DLL or OCX. Am I right?

Comment: i import the opos CCOS using the OCX . maybe its true and i use bad the open clause ... thabks Re0sless

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the 32 bit driver?

If you did, reimport the Com interface from the Ide.

Your installed driver does not match your tlb.pas generated wrapper.